# How to declare a 2D vector consist 2D vectors?

Tags: c++, vector, c++17, stdvector

This is confusing me in c++ (17)
I want to declare a 2 dimension vector with any size which each member is again a 2D vector itself.
I want to make empty vectors with known size. In fact I want its size to be set at declaration.
For a better picture , imagine a classic sodoku puzzle with 9 houses in 3x3 grid which each house has 9 cells in 3x3 grid.

```
    #include<iostream>
    #include <vector>
    using cell_t = std::vector<std::vector<int> >;
    using board_t = std::vector<std::vector<cell_t> >;
    cell_t temp(3, std::vector<int>(3)); //this would be a 2D vector member
```

Now the problem:

```
     board_t test(3,std::vector<cell_t>(3,std::vector<int>(3)));//this won't work
```

compiler errors:
Error   C2440   '': cannot convert from 'initializer list' to 'std::vector>'    Training2   main.cpp

and

Error (active)  E0289   no instance of constructor "std::vector<_Ty, _Alloc>::vector [with _Ty=cell_t, _Alloc=std::allocator]" matches the argument list    Training2   main.cpp    91

I wonder what do I missed? I know I can make it happen with a temporary `cell_t` like:

```
    cell_t temp(3, std::vector<int>(4));
    board_t test(3,std::vector<cell_t>(3,temp));
```

but I rather prefer using unknown object.
In the other hand I know how to use `resize()` or `push_back()` in favor to resize vectors to desirable sizes. But isn't it more faster to make this happen at the declaration rather than doing additional processes? because I want empty vectors

Comment: yo need to separate the characters `>` because this `>>` is a bit operator, so the code should look like this `using cell_t = std::vector< std::vector<int> >;`

Comment: imho this is one of those rare cases where a c-array is much more appropriate. Why not `int x[9][9]` ? Or use `std::array` but unless you want to change the size at runtime there is no need for vectors

Comment: @GuillermoGonzález this isnt true anymore since c++11

Comment: what is "the problem" ? Please include the compiler error

Comment: Perhaps you meant `board_t test(3,std::vector<cell_t>(3, cell_t(3,std::vector<int>(3))));`?

Comment: If for some reason you don't want to use `temp`, just inline its initializer where `temp` would otherwise go: `board_t test(3,std::vector<board_t>(3, cell_t(3, std::vector<int>(3))));`

Comment: "I want to make empty vectors with known size". Empty vectors have a known size. That size is zero.

Comment: If the inner dimensions are fixed, you'd be better off with a _one_ dimensional vector and some index mapping. You're causing a lot of unnecessary indirection and excess memory management.

Comment: @Caleth Yes I meant cell_t in problem line. and updated the post with compiler error.
in original code I have different identifiers and I changed them to be more intuitive.

Comment: @MarshallClow I know they have zero size . the problem as I mentioned is to create the board with non zero size at declartion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the problem is to define a vector of `cell_t` declaration.

```
     board_t test(3,std::vector<cell_t>(3,std::vector<int>(3)))
    //                        @a^^^^^^^  @b^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

@a we have a vector of `cell_t` but @b we describe a 'vector of int'
that's the problem.
we should go by `cell_t(3,std::vector<int>(3)` instead of @b
it should goes like this:

```
    board_t test(3, std::vector<cell_t>(3, cell_t(3, std::vector<int>(3))));
```

Answer (score 3):

Your current type definitions make it easy to have non-square cells and boards, and you have lots of indirection to reach an element. If you encapsulate that in a class, your initialisers can lose much of the repetition you currently have.

```
struct index_t {
    std::size_t x;
    std::size_t y;
};

template <typename T>
class square_matrix {
    std::size_t size;
    std::vector<T> elems;

    std::size_t position(index_t index) { return index.x + (index.y * size); }

public:
    square_matrix(std::size_t size, T elem = {}) : size(size), elems(size * size, elem) {}
    T& operator[](index_t index) { return elems[position(index)]; }
    const T& operator[](index_t index) const { return elems[position(index)]; }
};

using cell_t = square_matrix<int>;
using board_t = square_matrix<cell_t>;

board_t test(3, cell_t(3));
```

Comment: This is an inspiring  idea and it is absolutely smart. I totally appreciate it.
but this is not what I intended to do.
as it turns out I have to write functions like size() myself. 
as an aside I implement the code and it gave me a 3 sized array of  9 linear array and not a 3x3 array.
my question simply is that is there any way to declare such thing?